# SQL Server 2008 R2: Match the given pattern

Tags: sql-server, regex, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with 1 column as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    Cola VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('414F2D363030323831');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('123456789');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('123456789D');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('A123456789');
```

**Note**: I want to match the pattern which contains both alphabets and numbers. And that pattern will be anywhere in the given string.

According to the given example the expected result should be:

```
Cola
--------------------
414F2D363030323831
123456789D
A123456789
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LIKE`:

**[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/371216)**

```
SELECT *
FROM #test
WHERE Cola LIKE '%[0-9]%'
  AND Cola LIKE '%[A-Za-z]%'
```

Or using `PATINDEX`:

```
SELECT *
FROM #test
WHERE PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Cola) > 0
  AND PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z]%', Cola) > 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much. According to the time constraints to accept answer I need to wait till 10 min. But till the time up vote for sure.

Comment: you are a machine @Lad2025

Comment: @Jonathan Yup, I get CAPTCHA before I post this answer, but I passed. My creator is clever ;)

Comment: @Jonathan, Hahaha.. My words.

Comment: @Jonathan he has machine with black magic not only machine :P

Comment: @mak before we think of this guy is posting answer

Comment: @tinka basically i think he is Sql Vampire ...hehe

Comment: @Jonathan I've been disclosed ;) Now I need to create new account.

Comment: i didn't get you @lad2025

Comment: @Jonathan This was supposed to be joke. Forgive me my lack sense of humour. I am just machine ;)

Comment: haha now i laughed at it..even in sense of humour also you are typical lad @lad2025